# File.ReadAllText() not working in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, text

I am trying to read a text file on .net however it keeps saying that the file could not be found this is the code I am using

`@code { string ShipText = File.ReadAllText("~/txt/site.txt"); }`

I am not sure what is happening

Comment: File paths don't start with ~.

Comment: File.ReadAllText doesnt resolve the server path via the ~.  You must first resolve the server path and then concatenate it with the /txt/site.txt part.

Comment: Yes this is thank you so much